# Faster way of using fortran with octave

Tags: fortran, octave

I am trying to mix fortran with octave for some of my works.

I created a matrix in fortran and wrote that in a datafile with the following command.

```
do i=1,n
write(1,*) (/(a(i,j),j=1,n)/)
end do
```

Then I am loading this matrix in octave using dlmread and diagonalising the matrix using eigs there. Then again the array containing the eigenvalues is saved in a file in octave.

After that I am loading the file in fortran and reading that array.

The drawback of this method is, it takes a huge time to write the matrix and read, and also it takes space like 2gb for a 10k*10k matrix. Is there any other way of calling the octave routines like eigs in fortran to make it faster?

Comment: Writing to file is always going to be slow; so your question boils down to "How do I call Octave from FORTRAN", right? What about using BLAS/LAPACK directly? IIRC, at least in MATLAB, the linear algebra libraries are traditional FORTRAN ones anyway.

Comment: BLAS, LAPACK become a big mess to use because of innumerous number of arguments in the subroutine to be called compared to a simple eigs command in octave. Also, I need to use sparse matrices which can be done in ARPACK only in fortran. I am very new in using them and do not have any little idea on how to use that library. The documentation(ARPACK particularly) is extremely difficult to understand(each subroutine takes 10 to 15 arguments) for a newbie compared to eigs. If not possible in octave, suggestions on using some other open source software for this purpose is also welcome.

Comment: Is your matrix symmetric or Hermitian or anything nice like that. Dsyev, the routine for a real symmetric matrix in LAPACK, is pretty easy to use - it only has 8 argument, one of which is an error flag. But note an O(10k) matrix is reasonably chunky, you will have to wait a while for the results - if you want to go bigger you will probably need to start investigating using parallel diagonalisers

Comment: Actually, the matrices I am using are sparse, and ARPACK would be better suited for this. I know how to use dysev more or less, thanks for mentioning btw. My problem is mainly in using ARPACK. That's why I am trying to switch to octave, which has a nice eigs routine, and is able to do calculations for even 10k*10k matrix pretty fast.

Comment: So why not switch everything to Octave?

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking to do this has no other option. :)

Comment: No, I am just writing the matrix with all zeroes and non zero elements, and finding the eigenvalues using eigs. I do not know what is CSR format. I shall check it in google as you suggested.

Comment: You can cal Octave functionality from your Fortran program: http://wiki.octave.org/Fortran

Comment: Or vice-versa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711082/4183191